# Update Prompt for ClickOnce using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

Just had 2 questions.

1) I am writing a simple program in C# just to test out how to set up updating, However the program automatically updates ( I am using ClickOnce) and I was wondering is there any way to prompt the user to update?

2) I am publishing my project to a localhost, and I have published it about five times (v 1_0_0_1 - 1_0_0_5) and the folders are stored as such, however, when I publish, it changes ALL of the different versions, not just the latest one. I am trying to allow version control where I can allow a user to go back to a previous version.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

After the user installs your app for the first time, every time after that when the application is started it will check for an update. If there is an update it will ask the user if they want to update to that version.

[image]

This happens by default and you can even prevent them from opening the application if they select not to update. (Preventing the program from opening if the user does not update is not the default configuration but can be set in the publishing wizard or properties of the application)

Also you should know that publishing the application will not cause you to lose or overwrite all of your previous deployed versions. They are all still there under root/Application Files. You will see the latest version though because the app will look at the manafest file and that will tell the app which version to run. If you wanted to push out a later version you would change the manifest to point to that version.

However, a single user will not be able to choose which version they want. Once they choose to update they will be on that version until you push out a different one. This is for security and compatibility so that your users are on the same version once they choose to update and you don't have a bunch of different people running different versions whenever they feel like it!